# Serialize RichTextBox including size, backcolor, position

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xml-serialization

Currently I am using a method like

```
    var content = new TextRange(myRichtextBox.NoteBody.Document.ContentStart, myRichtextBox.NoteBody.Document.ContentEnd);
    using (FileStream fs = File.Create(SavePath))
    {
        content.Save(fs, DataFormats.XamlPackage);
    }
```

Which is working great to save the *content* of my RichTextBox. What I'm having trouble with is finding a method to save the entire control.

I've tried using `XmlSerializer` which has trouble serializing an object like this because there are immutables and interface inheritances. I get the error `There was an error reflecting type  <my window type>`. I've tried using XmlWriter but without much luck.

I'm thinking of creating a second XML file which saves a few key properties of the RTB that are important to me plus a reference to my XAML serialization of the RTB content. But before I go through all that effort of creating an XML document from scratch which avoids the un-serializable elements I want to know: Are there more options? How can I save the state of my RichTextBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [MSDN Forum Posting](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/1d643002-6d03-40f3-8248-90201e3aa0d3) you can use the [XamlWriter.Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms613438) Method of the `System.Windows.Markup` Namespace. I modified the given example for a RichtextBox and tested.

*Definition of XamlWriter Class from MSDN Link:*

> Provides a single static Save method (multiple overloads) that can be used for limited XAML serialization of provided run-time objects into XAML markup.

**Xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <RichTextBox Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="richTextBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Background="#FF00F7F7">
            <FlowDocument>
                <Paragraph>
                    <Run Text="Hello World"/>
                </Paragraph>
            </FlowDocument>
        </RichTextBox>
        <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="92,164,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
        <Label Content="Label" Height="221" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="216,12,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;


namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string savedRichTextBox = XamlWriter.Save(richTextBox1);
            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Temp\Test.xaml", savedRichTextBox);

            StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(savedRichTextBox);
            XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);

            RichTextBox rtbLoad = (RichTextBox)XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);

            label1.Content = rtbLoad;
        }
    }
}
```

**Test.xaml**

```
<RichTextBox Background="#FF00F7F7" Name="richTextBox1" Width="200" Height="100" Margin="228,173,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"><FlowDocument PagePadding="5,0,5,0" AllowDrop="True"><Paragraph>Hello World</Paragraph></FlowDocument></RichTextBox>
```

Comment: Oh yeah. Much slicker. I had to put a `File.ReadAllLines` in there before the `StringReader` because my save and load are two different methods. But this seems to be working very well. I'll have to work with it today

Comment: I tried to scale this up to serialize a whole window and it writes what I think to be a logical XML file but it always fails to read the file with the `XamlReader.Load`. It give me a `XamlParseException`. Can this only be used for one object at a time?

Comment: I have not used it for large Items, it does say limited, what happens if you stop short of the window and serialize the Main Grid. Here is a [Link describing the Limitations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754193)

Comment: Great link! And an interesting read. My file's failure points are some of the exact items they discuss

Comment: @Brad Glad to be of some help